# Error: unknown filesystem. Grub rescue>

Tags: windows-10, файловая-система, grub, kali-linux, удаление

Вчера при отчистке, случайно удалил диск с Kali Linux, на котором был загрузчик GRUB, сегодня же выскакивает такая ошибка. Пытался зайти в bios, но он не открывается. С загрузочной флешки тоже не получается. Где win10 - пишет не найдена ос. А на той, где Kali - пишет unknown filesystem.
Для наглядности показал, что доступно. Умоляю, помогите решить.

[image: Ошибка для наглядности.]